# Update on table by executing a T-SQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, procedure

I need to update column in each empty row by data from procedure.

The problem is that I need a unique value for each record. Procedure returns it, but I don't know how to make it happen.

The results I got so far are same in every single row - remember that when I exec procedure it check table for existing values and gives me the unique value. How do I update every time other value by this procedure?

```
declare @ean varchar(40)

exec dbo.generateEAN 1, '', @ean output

update t 
set Twr_Ean = @ean 
from dbo.table t  
where t.Code = ''
```

Comment: Why you need an SP? What's the SP code? What do you mean by _"Empty"_ is that mean _''_ or `NULL`? Please provide the SP code.

Comment: Can you share `generateEAN`  code? If it could be refactored to return a table of EANs, rather simple script for updating the table could be created. Otherwise the last resource is a loop.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is true, but it sounds like you want to apply your function to every row in your table, which to me sounds like a reason to look into `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Scalar Functions ? Perhaps easier than Stored procedures for an in-line update statement. Here's a simple snippet. But performance degrades when working over a large dataset. You may want to rethink how you approach your problem.

> create function dbo.ufn_mypower (@x int)
>   returns int with execute as caller 
>   as
>   begin  return power( @x, 2 )
>   end
>   go
>
> create table updatewithfunction
>    ( originalvalue int null
>     ,calculatedvalue int null   )
>
> insert updatewithfunction ( originalvalue ) 
>   values
>    (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)
>
> update updatewithfunction 
>   set calculatedvalue = dbo.ufn_mypower(originalvalue)
>   where calculatedvalue is null and originalvalue >= 4
>
> select *from updatewithfunction